# Android BroadcastListener reboot loop

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement a feature where an android phone reboots daily at 4:30am.  To accomplish this I am using a rooted phone with an app running as system.  The reboot works as it should however after the first reboot every time the app starts again on boot it just immediately reboots.

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Set the time for the nightly reboot
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// Schedule the nightly reboot
Intent rebootIntent = new Intent(this, NightlyReboot.class);
PendingIntent pendingRebootIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, rebootIntent, 0);
manager.setRepeating(RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingRebootIntent);
```

**NightlyReboot.java**

```
public class NightlyReboot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        pm.reboot("Nightly Reboot");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.theoomf.hotspot">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".WatchDog"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".NightlyReboot"
        android:permission="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
</application>
```

Comment: You need to check if the time you're setting for the alarm has already passed for today, and add a day to the `Calendar` if it has. When you set an alarm with a time in the past, it fires immediately. I should also mention that setting a repeating alarm for this is kinda pointless, since you have to set the alarm again after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Should have read the Android docs better.  Since I am setting the start time to a time in the past if it is past 4:30am when the app launches it will send a broadcast to the receiver immediately per the Android docs.  Modified to the following to fix the issue.

```
    // Set the time for the nightly reboot to 4:30am.
    Calendar rebootTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    rebootTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    rebootTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    rebootTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    rebootTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // If reboot time is in the past then add 1 day.
    if (rebootTime.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        rebootTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    // Schedule the nightly reboot
    Intent rebootIntent = new Intent(this, NightlyReboot.class);
    PendingIntent pendingRebootIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, rebootIntent, 0);
    manager.setRepeating(RTC_WAKEUP, rebootTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingRebootIntent);
```